# A "Trivial" Smooth Structure

Tags: manifolds

Let M be a topological manifold of dimension $n$. Suppose that there exists a homeomorphism
$$
\phi \colon M \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n
$$
defined for all $x \in M$. That is, $\phi$ is a continuous bijection with a continuous inverse. Thus, it would be appropriate to call $\phi$ a chart on $M$ and, it seems to me, we could define an atlas $\mathcal{A}$ on $M$ consisting of the single chart $\phi$,
$$
\mathcal{A} := \{(\phi, M)\}
$$
Using this atlas, if my reasoning is correct, one can consider $M$ to be a smooth manifold. Therefore, any topological manifold $M$ for which there exists a homeomorphism $\phi \colon M \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ can actually be considered as a smooth manifold.

So, my question is, *Is this line of reasoning correct*?

All of these statements seem to follow directly from the definitions but it is somewhat counterintuitive in the sense that clearly not all homeomorphisms have smooth inverses. e.g., if $\phi(x) = x^3$, $\phi^{-1}(x) = x^{1/3}$ and it is easily seen that $\phi$ is a homeomorphism but the derivative of $\phi^{-1}$ does not exist at the origin.

Comment: Regarding your question about $x \mapsto x^3$, you might want to read [this part of Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_atlas#Confusion_about_terminology).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes that is correct.

As for your example on $\mathbb R$, there is a smooth manifold structure on $\mathbb R$ coming from the chart $x\mapsto x^3$, and for the reason you gave, this is not compatible with the standard smooth manifold structure coming from the chart $x\mapsto x$.

However, the smooth manifolds obtained in this way are diffeomorphic.  Let $\mathbb R_{\text{cube}}$ be $\mathbb R$ with the cubing chart, and let $\mathbb R_{\text{st}}$ be $\mathbb R$ with the standard atlas.  Then $f:\mathbb R_{\text{cube}}\to\mathbb R_{\text{st}}$ defined by $f(x)=x^3$ is a diffeomorphism.

It is generally the case that the structure you put on $M$ in this way is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$.  Somewhat analogous to turning a homeomorphism into a diffeomorphism in this way would be to induce a topology on a set using a bijection.  E.g., you could set up a rather unnatual topology on $[0,1]$ by choosing a bijection of $[0,1]$ with $\mathbb R$ and making it a homeomorphism.  Also somewhat analogous, you can put a complete metric on $(0,1)$ by choosing a homeomorphism of $(0,1)$ with $\mathbb R$ and making it an isometry.  In this case, the sequence $(1/n)$ will not be a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: I guess I'm missing something, but I don't see how $x \mapsto x^3$ is a diffeomorphism (meaning that it's a smooth homeomorphism with smooth inverse) since the derivative of the inverse map $x \mapsto x^{1/3}$ does not exist at the origin.

Comment: @3Sphere: To see that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable, you only need to check that for all charts $\phi:\mathbb R_{\text{cube}}\to\mathbb R$ and $\psi:\mathbb R_{\text{st}}\to\mathbb R$, the map $\phi\circ f^{-1}\circ \psi^{-1}:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable.  Note for example that if $\phi(x)=x^3$, this removes the singularity at the origin of $x\mapsto x^{1/3}$.